# JW Player captions loads on video pause

Tags: jwplayer, drupal-modules, drupal-8, closed-captions

I'm using custom JW player wrapper in Drupal 8. The JW player video loads on image click. **The issue is closed captions and settings are not loading when video starts on click of image.** They appears when video is paused and played again.

I want to load closed captions and settings icons first time when video is played and also start showing captions.

Comment: Could you please show your JW Player configuration? What you describe as desired behavior is the default when captions are detected in the player setup.